# Replace color in Svg files with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a lot of Svgs files, and I want to replace one specific color by an other.
I've not path id and set ids in over 600 files is too long. 
All the files have the same colors as the two in the example. I would like to select all elements with the color #EB1A21 and replace them with a variable containing another color. My svgs files are embed in object html tags.
I don't want save results in external files because the new colors are set in an input type=text by users, so I can't save all new coloured Svg file. I want them to be "dynamically" changed

The format of my file is like this

```
<svg>
  <g>
    <path style="fill:#EB1A21;" d="....."/>
    <path style="fill:#292B87;" d="....."/>
    <path style="fill:#EB1A21;" d="....."/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

and I want to show files like this :

```
<svg>
  <g>
    <path style="fill:#color1;" d="....."/>
    <path style="fill:#color2;" d="....."/>`
    <path style="fill:#color1;" d="....."/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Ps: sorry for my language i'm a french guy :)

Thanks in advance..

----SOLUTION----

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    for (i in mySvgFiles){
        var curImage = escape(mySvgFiles[i]);
        $("#contents").append('<object data="file.svg" type="image/svg+xml" onload="selectObj(this);"><object/  >');
    }

    function selectObj(my_object){
        var colorChoice1 = "#FF0000"
        var colorChoice2 = "#00FF00"
        var svgDoc = my_object.contentDocument;
        var svgRootemp = svgDoc.documentElement;
        colorize(svgRootemp, colorChoice1, colorChoice2);
    }

    function colorize(svgRoot, color1, color2){
        $("[style='fill:#292B87;']",svgRoot).css("fill", color1);
        $("[style='fill:#EB1A21;']",svgRoot).css("fill", color2);
    }
</script>
<div id="contents"></div>
```

If you have questions about this ask me :)

Comment: This is what CSS is for. Give the paths that have common colours a common CSS class then change the colours in the CSS class to whatever you want.

Comment: Please specify whether you want them to "dynamically" change (meaning you wish to control them in javascript/css) or do you want them permanently changed. Saying you have 600 files makes me feel like you wish to permanently change them, not dynamically change them (i.e. with javascript or css).

Comment: thanks it's corrected

Answer (score 0):

```
var color1 = "#00FF00";
var color2 = "#FF0000";

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("path").each(function () {
        var color = $(this).css("fill");
        if (color == "rgb(235, 26, 33)") {
            $(this).css("fill", color1);
        } else if (color == "rgb(41, 43, 135)") {
            $(this).css("fill", color2);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i dont find a way to do this working.

Comment: I would think that answer would require a bit more explanation ... Like adding jquery.